# Trigger a particular flow in Power Automate Desktop

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I want to trigger a particular flow in Power Automate Desktop. How can I do this instead of clicking on the run button against the flow manually? Is there a way?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/run-pad-flow

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/link-pad-flow-portal

Answer (score 1):

there are several ways for you to do this.

Let's say you wanna start a desktop flow by a http request (a post request for example). You can create a simple flow at your cloud PWA using the trigger below:
[image: Trigger for receiving post/get http requests]

and then call your desktop flow:
[image]

It depends on how you wanna trigger it, if you want you can use a recurrence trigger, the email one, etc.

Let me know if it helped you.